# Немного лирики про MVC в Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, mvc

В Laravel есть такой класс `BD`. С помощью него можно делать например так:

```
DB::table('orders')->selectRaw('price * ? as price_with_tax', [1.0825])->get();
```

Почему-то во всех примерах из интернета и оф. документации подобные конструкции используются в контроллере. Что, по моему мнению нарушает идею `MVC` и оно должно быть в модели.

Это я чего-то не понимаю и это бест практисес или в примерах его пихают в контроллер только для простоты понимания?

Comment: Зачем вообще использовать `DB::table`, это же сродни `mysqli_query`.

Comment: @РустамГимранов А что надо использовать?

Comment: Модели нужно использовать, описывать связи, и управлять коллекциями, а не полусырые запросы слать через фасады.

Comment: @РустамГимранов т.е. полусырые запросы уместно выносить в контроллер? Вопрос не про конкретно `DB::table`

Comment: Если и приходится использовать по каким бы то ни было причинам `selectRaw`, то опять же описываете [акцессоры](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) в модели. Это мое личное мнение, но есть категория людей, которые будут, извините, до "усрачки" доказывать, что это все не строгие правила и они имеют полное право использовать фреймворк как им вздумается. Вот и вся лирика. Нафиг она эта каша в контроллере не нужна.